# Using matplotlibs 'FuncAnimation' to plot data over a video

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some eyetracking data from participants that watched some short (12-14s) videos. Now to get an overview on the data I would like to plot the fixation over the video.

I found `matplotlib`s `FuncAnimation` that can create animations and could create an animation showing the fixations over the presentation of the video.

```
fig = plp.figure()
plp.xlim(0, 1920)
plp.ylim(0, 1080)
interval = 1000/sample_rate
frames = len (sub1[0][0])
graph, = plp.plot([],[],'o')
def animate(i):
    graph.set_data(sub1[0][0][:i+1], sub1[1][0][:i+1])
    return (graph,)
ani = FuncAnimation(fig, func=animate, frames=frames, interval=interval, blit=True)
#HTML(ani.to_html5_video())
```

I can also open and play the video using `cv2.VideoCapture` and plot my fixation over a frame and also overwrite frames.

```
fig, ax = plp.subplots(figsize=(10,10)) # create figure
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('Video.mp4') # open video file
fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS) # get video framerate
frame_time = 1.0/fps
counter = 0
while counter <75:
    ret, frame = cap.read() # get frame
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) #convert in correct colourspace
    ax.imshow(frame) # plot frame
    ax.plot(data.X_Coord[(data.TimeStamp>counter*frame_time)&(data.TimeStamp<frame_time*(counter+1))],
            data.Y_Coord[(data.TimeStamp>counter*frame_time)&(data.TimeStamp<frame_time*(counter+1))],'.') #plot eyetracking data
    counter+=1
    time.sleep(1.0/fps) # let python wait till it is time for the next frame
cap.release()
```

**But** I cannot create an animation using `FuncAnimation`. I tried this:

```
fig, ax = plp.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('Video.mp4') 
def animate(i):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    ax.imshow(frame)
    ax.plot(data.X_Coord[(data.TimeStamp>counter*frame_time)&(data.TimeStamp<frame_time*(counter+1))],
            data.Y_Coord[(data.TimeStamp>counter*frame_time)&(data.TimeStamp<frame_time*(counter+1))],'o')
    time.sleep(1.0/fps)
    counter += 1
    return (ax,)
cap.release()
ani = FuncAnimation(fig, func=animate)
```

and some variations, but none is working. I am not sure if I use this animation function in the right way. In the most examples it returns a graph (as in my example), but this does not work with my frame (at least I think so).

I am working in Jupyter Notebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay figured it out.
Silly me closed the `VideoCaption` before calling the `FuncAnimation`
For every one that wants to plot data over a video:

```
%matplotlib inline
fig, ax = plp.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('in.mp4') 
num_frames = int (cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
frame_time = 1.0/fps

graph, = ax.plot([],[],'o')
ret,frame = cap.read()
frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
im = ax.imshow (frame)
def animate(i):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        im.set_array(frame)
    graph.set_data (data.X_Coord[(data.TimeStamp>i*frame_time)&(data.TimeStamp<frame_time*(i+1))],
            data.Y_Coord[(data.TimeStamp>i*frame_time)&(data.TimeStamp<frame_time*(i+1))])
    time.sleep(frame_time)
    return ax, im,

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, func=animate, frames=num_frames, interval=frame_time)
Writer = animation.writers['ffmpeg']
writer = Writer(fps=fps, metadata=dict(artist='Me'), bitrate=1800)
ani.save('out.mp4',writer=writer)
cap.release()
```